# ssh from parameter laravel

Tags: php, laravel, ssh

I want to create a form like this.

```
Host __________
user __________
pass __________
port _________
```

to connect the ssh via laravel.
I see config in remote.php is

```
'connections' => [
        'production' => [
            'host'      => '222.222.222.222',
            'username'  => 'root',
            'password'  => '',
            'key'       => '',
            'keytext'   => '',
            'keyphrase' => '',
            'agent'     => '',
            'timeout'   => 10,
        ],
    ],
```

but i don't want to force the config.
I just want like

```
SSH::connect('222.222.222.222','root','1234',22);
```

How can do that?
Sorry my english.

Comment: Doesn't seem like you can do that from the Laravel Collective documentation. Why not just setup different connection arrays and use the into('connection name') method they provide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the laravel way to set your config runtime!

```
config(['remote.connections.production' => array(
                'host'      => '$host,
            'username'  => $un,
            'password'  => $pw,
            'key'       => '',
            'keytext'   => '',
            'keyphrase' => '',
            'agent'     => '',
            'timeout'   => 10,

            )]);
```